# Circular resource dependency error in Zend framework 1.12.11

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework

I have running a Zend1 Application on AWS servers.
It is zend 1.12.11 and php 5.6 on AWS, I want to set it up on my local machine, On localhost I have php 7.3.  I want to setup on my localhost I am getting this error message. Can anybody please let me know either it is due to php version difference or how can I fix this/ Thanks in advance.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception: Circular resource dependency detected in /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:674
Stack trace:
#0 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(641): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
#1 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(598): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
#2 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/application/Bootstrap.php(43): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
#3 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/application/Bootstrap.php(52): Bootstrap::fetchResource()
#4 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Bigwords/BaseController.php(82): Bootstrap::fetchClientvars()
#5 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(133): Bigwords_BaseController->init()
#6 /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(281): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct()

## in /home/stage2_bigwords_com/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336

Answer (score 0):

What happened there is that in your bootstrap you have something like the following code:

```
class Bootstrap {

  public function _initDb() {
    $session = $this->bootstrap('session');
  }
  public function _initSession() {
    $db = $this->bootstrap('db');
  }
}
```

As you can see to get DB initialized, you need session initialized. But to init session, you need DB. That is a circular dependency. You need to work around it somehow.

Obviously in your code it does not have to be session and db, but any resource that is initialized in bootstrap.